# How to display image in a @mui/x-data-grid table?

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm a react.js beginner. when I'm trying to add an image avatar to my MUI table, I got the following error. "TypeError: params.rows is undefined"
I'll put my code below.

```
import React from 'react'
```

import "./userList.css"
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

export default function UserList() {

```
const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'user', headerName: 'User', width: 200, renderCell: (params)=>{
      return (
        <div>
          <img src={params.rows.avatar} alt='' />
          {params.rows.username}
        </div>
      )
    } },
    { field: 'email', headerName: 'E-mail', width: 130 },
    {
      field: 'status',
      headerName: 'Status',
      width: 90,
    },
    {
      field: 'transaction',
      headerName: 'Transaction',
      width: 100,
    },
    
  ];
  
  const rows = [
    { id: 1, 
    username: 'Harry Potter', avatar:"https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/bebad102-7f40-4941-99cd-54366113003e/avatar-08.png", 
    email:"Harry@gmail.com", 
    status:"Active",
    transaction:"$120" 
    },];

return (
    <div className="userList">
        <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
)
```

}

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghb1e.png)

Comment: Try console.log params to see what properties it has. I think it has value param that you could use, but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 11):

I see some data structure problems in your code and components not used.

First one being avatars, can be set using MUI components, such as.. `<Avatar>`
Avatar Component MUI

Which can be added through:

```
<Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
```

But to use it, you've of course to import it, so, other than the `DataGrid`, you import also the `Avatar` component:

```
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
```

---

By giving an interpretation to what you're doing about the rows, there's a problem. Because you are trying to render into the column `user` the values of: `username` and `avatar`. To achieve that, you need to have them both on that. I took a `Datagrid` fiddle, pasted your code and made some fix, in a way you can see what I mean.

Here is the fiddle: [DataGrid Text + Avatar column example](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-text-avatar-example-v6b9l?file=/demo.js:0-1251)

And here's the code in the fiddle also revised a little bit.

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";

export default function UserList() {
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
    {
      field: "user",
      headerName: "User",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        console.log(params);
        return (
          <>
            <Avatar src={params.value.avatar} />
            {params.value.username}
          </>
        );
      }
    },
    { field: "email", headerName: "E-mail", width: 130 },
    {
      field: "status",
      headerName: "Status",
      width: 90
    },
    {
      field: "transaction",
      headerName: "Transaction",
      width: 100
    }
  ];

  const rows = [
    {
      id: 1,
      user: {
        username: "Harry Potter",
        avatar:
          "https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/bebad102-7f40-4941-99cd-54366113003e/avatar-08.png"
      },
      email: "Harry@gmail.com",
      status: "Active",
      transaction: "$120"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <DataGrid
        autoHeight
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

As you can see, it's very important the part that you defined, 5 columns in the `columns` variable:

1. id
2. user
3. email
4. status
5. transaction

Whilst the values provided in rows, included 6 rows. This was the first problem. Restructure the code to accomodate the column structure the `DataGrid` component is expecting to receive.

So instead of:

```
{ id: 1, 
    username: 'Harry Potter', avatar:"https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/bebad102-7f40-4941-99cd-54366113003e/avatar-08.png", 
    email:"Harry@gmail.com", 
    status:"Active",
    transaction:"$120" 
    }
```

Using the column name `user` to keep the data of either the `username` and the `avatar` together. To access such data in the `params`, you should go through `params.value`, which allows direct access to the column values, instead of going through params.row, which gives you access to the whole row, but you should do something like `params.row.user.username` and `params.row.user.avatar`. It's longer, and I'd use it only if I want to join some existing columns to put together a new one with concatenated values. Otherwise I think it's easier to use `params.value`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a typo: it is not `params.rows`, but `params.row`. So you can access the row information like this:

```
{ field: 'user', headerName: 'User', width: 200, renderCell: (params)=>{
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={params.row.avatar} alt='' />
      {params.row.username}
    </div>
  )
} },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
field: 'user',
headerName: 'User',
width: 150,
editable: true,
renderCell: (params) => <img src={params.value} />, },
```

in this cell **params.value**

[image]

Comment: He also wants to have access to the username, so he need multiple information from the row, not from the cell I think

Comment: yes you are right for multiple info use ***params.row***